# Хранение html js css в ресурсах

Tags: delphi, webbrowser

Как поместить все html, css, js файлы в ресурсы и потом загружать в webbrowser? При этом в самой html странице подключены файлы js и css, необходимо, чтобы это всё работало!

Comment: 1. Положить в ресурсы. 2. Достать из ресурсов во временные файлы. 3. Указать браузеру на временные файлы.

Comment: А на премую не как?

Answer (score 0):

Я не совсем понимаю, зачем нужен подобный финт ушами (прятать исходные файлы? Так они всё равно будут загружены в браузер), однако, сделать подобное можно. Я покажу простейший вариант, а дальше уже сами усложняйте, если есть необходимость. Многофайловый код непосредственно подключить не получится, придётся копировать всё в один (и CSS, и JS должны будут располагаться вместе с HTML-кодом в одном файле). Если это вам не нравится, придётся делать так, как предложено @kami.

Возьмём мой любимый HTML-код с яваскриптом и сохраним в качестве TXT-файла (пусть будет "test.txt". Обратите внимание, у меня кодировка UTF-8):

```
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>

  <p>Начало документа...</p>
  <script>
    document.write( 'Привет, Мир!' );
  </script>

  <p>...Конец документа</p>

</body>

</html>
```

Добавим его как ресурсный в проект руками:

```
TESTJS RCDATA "test.txt"
```

или через меню **Project/Resources and Images** (как RCDATA) под именем `TESTJS`

Теперь, собственно, как загрузить код из ресурса:

```
var
  WebBrowser1: TWebBrowser;
  rs : TResourceStream;

<...>

// Инициализируем WebBrowser
  WebBrowser1.Navigate('about:blank');
  while WebBrowser1.ReadyState < READYSTATE_INTERACTIVE do
    Application.ProcessMessages;

  if Assigned(WebBrowser1.Document) then
    begin
       try
         // Организуем поток с нашим HTML-кодом
         rs := TResourceStream.Create(HInstance, 'TESTJS', RT_RCDATA);
         try
           // На всякий случай передвигаем указатель потока на начало
           rs.Seek(0,0);
           // загружаем код в WebBrowser
          (WebBrowser1.Document as IPersistStreamInit).Load(TStreamAdapter.Create(rs));
         finally
           //
         end;
       finally
         rs.Free;
       end;
    end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно напрямую загружать из ресурсов. TWebBrowser отлично с этим справляется.
Я делал это так:
1) Готовим все необходимые файлы (html, js, css), убеждаемся что все работает, все красиво.
2) Создаем ресурсный файл. (Я компилирую его в ручную через командную строку `brcc32.exe Resources.rc`).

Содержимое файла Resources.rc

```
style css "path/style.css"
script js "path/script.js"
content html "path/content.html"
```

3) Добавляем в проект. Загружаем страницу из ресурсов: `WebBrowser1.Navigate('res://' + Application.ExeName + '/html/content');`
4) Наблюдаем, что страница загрузилась без стилей и скриптов.
5) Правим html с учетом изменившихся путей:

```
<head>
    <link href="../css/style" type=text/css rel=stylesheet>
    <script src="../js/script"></script>
</head>
```

6) Перекомпилируем ресурс и программу. Profit!

Comment: С картинками и прочим контентом на странице можно смело поступать также, добавляя их в ресурс. Главное правильные пути указать. И в случае с обновлением страницы (F5) вариант предложенный Виктором приведет к показу этого самого 'about:blank', а в таком варианте страница снова подгрузится из ресурсов.